# Installing NativeScript environment, issue with cocoapods on M1 mac in 2023

Tags: macos, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

I am having issues with installing NativeScript. My machine uses a M1 chip, I'm reading M1 and cocoapods have issues. Other SO answers are not fixing the issue, and some are outdated. Hoping we can get an updated answer.

I followed the mac instructions on [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios) guide:

`sudo ns doctor ios`
returns all checkmarks up until

```
✖ WARNING: CocoaPods is not installed or is not configured properly. 
 You will not be able to build your projects for iOS if they contain plugin with CocoaPod file.
```

How can I properly configure cocoapods for M1 chip?

---

I have uninstalled and reinstalled cocoapods using gem

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
for each cocoapod gem in "gem list cocoapods"
`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-NAME`

and reinstalled
`sudo gem install cocoapods`

my zshrc for gem installation
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:$PATH"

Result is the same error.

I have also tried using home brew to install and uninstall cocoapods
`brew install --cask cocoapods`/`brew install cocoapods`
and
`brew uninstall cocoapods`

my zshrc for brew installation
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:$PATH"

Result is the same error

While installed, both options return version 1.12.1 when calling "pod --version"

Another thing I have been seeing in other SO posts is to try arch
`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods`
this returns
arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable

Opening the terminal using rosetta does not fix this issue for me.

This command does work however:
`arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods`
pod --version works properly (1.12.1)

Result is the same error

---

I have uninstalled and reinstalled many times in different ways, I have followed the accepted answer of countless SO questions, and nothing is correctly configuring cocoapods. The other needed gem "xcodeproj" works just fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Denkan's answer on this thread fixed the issues with cocoapods.
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5447

I needed to manually recreate the tns doctor steps.